# What's wrong with my form?

Tags: php

I had a form which was unstyled, so I decided to style it a bit.

Form that does nothing:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $_POST['username']; ?>">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">API Key</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <p class="form-control-static"><?php if(strpos(file_get_contents("keys.php"),base64_encode($_POST['username'])) !== false) {echo "API Key already exists";} else { echo base64_encode($_POST['username']); }?></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Get API Key</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Working form:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
  Username: <input type="text" name="username" value"<?php echo $_POST['username']; ?>" /><br /><br />
  Key: <input type="text" value="
  <?php if(strpos(file_get_contents("./keys.php"),base64_encode($_POST['username'])) !== false) {
    echo "API Key already exists";
  } else { echo base64_encode($_POST['username']); }?>" readonly /><br />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I'm not really sure what's wrong.

The broken form doesn't POST the data, thus it doesn't display it.

Comment: it is very important to use `<input type=submit`, not `<button`

Comment: It doesn't POST the data that I'm putting in, whereas the other form does.

Basically what it's supposed to do is push the data to a PHP script which puts the data into another file (keys.php). It's not doing that with the first form I showed, but it does work with the second one.

Comment: @Lashane Whoops, sorry, copied that from Bootstrap's site. Regardless, it didn't fix it.

Comment: `<button type="submit">` will work, too.

Comment: @Lashane I call bull on your comment. There's not difference between *input type submit* and *button*.

Comment: Rendered HTML of the broken form would be more helpful than the PHP in seeing where the syntax error is.  Learn to use view source in browser.

Comment: @developerwjk I'm well aware of how to use view source. I assumed it might involve something with me PHP code. If you want to know what rendered HTML looks like, just remove the PHP yourself.

Comment: @Cody You want people to help? Make it easy for them, not harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I finally understand your issue.  Its not that the form doesn't POST.  It goes to the next page.  No, its that the values get lost.

So why do the values get lost?  Because you have no `name` attribute on your inputs!

This:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $_POST['username']; ?>">
```

Should be:

```
<input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $_POST['username']; ?>">
```

In fact, shouldn't `placeholder` be `value`?

Answer (score -1):

This line:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $_POST['username']; ?>">
```

is missing the `/>` at the end.

Also, in the working one, you have a

```
Key: <input type="text" value="...
```

The one that is not working:

```
<p class="form-control-static"><?php if(strpos(file_get_contents...
```

You are missing an input hidden or something like that.

Comment: Hmm, thanks. That second part is intentional. I just want it to show the API key.

Comment: Tried fixing the />, didn't do anything though.

Comment: I don't want the second part to be submitted. All it's doing is sitting there until my Username form posts, because then it's turned into base64 and supposed to be printed back out.

Comment: @Cody you forgot the first `input name="username"`!

Comment: Or do I need to put it as an input anyway?